# NodeJS "http" localAddress not working with same subnet on multiple network interfaces

Tags: node.js, http, network-programming

I work on an embedded system (Ubuntu 14.04) that uses 2 hardware ethernet interfaces, both having a Link-Local Address alias as you can see here (using `ip a`):

```
eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 3000
    link/ether 00:1e:2d:00:40:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.251.25.206/24 brd 10.251.25.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.11.1/16 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb qlen 3000
    link/ether 00:1e:2d:00:40:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.43.182.23/20 brd 192.43.191.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.10.1/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Some cameras are connected on both interfaces, each of them having a link-local address, I need to send http requests to all of the cameras, but I am having trouble sending http requests using the official `http` module of NodeJS to these cameras (actually I tried with the `request module` too, but it doesn't work).
An option for the `request` function called `localAddress` allows to use the correct interface/address, however, it does not work when both interfaces have the same subnetwork (link-local here).

Let's suppose that my system does not have the link-local aliases and we have 1 camera connected on each interface :

- camera0: connected to eth0 with the address 169.254.10.50
- camera1: connected to eth1 with the address 169.254.11.50

Now let's follow these steps:

- I cannot communicate with the cameras yet as I am not on the same subnet.
- I add the alias 169.254.10.1/16 to eth0.
- => Now I can send a request to camera0 (setting the option `localAddress` to 169.254.10.1 or not is the same, it is smart enough to find it)
- I add the alias 169.254.11.1/16 to eth1
- => I can still send a request to camera0 (setting `localAddress` or not), but, I cannot send a request to camera1, even if I set `localAddress` to 169.254.11.1
- Next, I delete the alias on eth0, then create it again
- => Now I can send a request to camera1, whetever the value of `localAddress`, but I cannot access camera0 anymore, even if I set `localAddress` to 169.254.10.1

The error appearing is EHOSTUNREACH.

Am I doing something wrong ? Is that a bug ? Is it a limit of Linux/IP ? How can I be able to send requests to both eth without having to delete/create aliases ?

Using tcpdump I see who-has requests with no answer:

```
08:54:31.236974 ARP, Request who-has 169.254.11.50 tell 169.254.11.1, length 28
08:54:32.283507 ARP, Request who-has 169.254.11.50 tell 169.254.11.1, length 28
08:54:33.307486 ARP, Request who-has 169.254.11.50 tell 169.254.11.1, length 28
08:55:02.383014 ARP, Request who-has 169.254.11.50 tell 169.254.11.1, length 28
08:55:03.387588 ARP, Request who-has 169.254.11.50 tell 169.254.11.1, length 28
08:55:04.411586 ARP, Request who-has 169.254.11.50 tell 169.254.11.1, length 28
```

However `ping -I eth0 169.254.10.50` and `ping -I eth1 169.254.11.50` work with both aliases set in network interfaces at the same time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to make it work by modifying the route tables/rules.

Here is what I did to make it work :

- First I added 2 tables `lla_eth0` and `lla_eth1` ('lla' stands for link-local address) :

```
# echo -e "1\tlla_eth0" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
# echo -e "2\tlla_eth1" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

note that the numbers '1' and '2' are the IDs of the tables, they should be unique, and in my case they were not used.

- Then on each table, I want to route every destination address within the network 169.254.0.0/16 to their corresponding interface :

```
# ip route add 169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 table lla_eth0
# ip route add 169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1 table lla_eth1
```

- Finally, I set 2 rules, every time the source 169.254.10.1 is used we use the table lla_eth0, and similarly with 169.254.11.1 and lla_eth1 :

```
# ip rule add from 169.254.10.1 table lla_eth0
# ip rule add from 169.254.11.1 table lla_eth1
```